# Folding results in an empty list

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to make a function that will turn `[1..10]` into `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10]`. What I have so far is `prepend` which will add a number of the same element to the start of a list:

```
-- prepend value num times to the start of list (eg: prepend [] 5 1 = [1,1,1,1,1]
prepend :: [a] -> Int -> a -> [a]
prepend [] _ _ = []
prepend list 0 _ = list
prepend list num value = prepend (value : list) (num - 1) value
```

To create the final list I'm using `foldl` like this:

`foldl (\acc x -> (prepend acc 2 x)) [] [1..10]`

I expected it to go through `[1..10]`, and for each element add 2 of x onto acc, but when I put that into GHCI I just get back `[]`

I'm new to Haskell coming from a C/C++ background

Comment: why not `concatMap`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap?

Comment: to your problem: have you checked if your prepend works? (hint: what does it do with the very first `acc` - which of course will be `[]` - what will the second `acc` be then?)

Comment: Removing the `[] _ _ = []` pattern worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an empty list, and you want to prepend some elements, do you *really* want to return the empty list? No. So remove the following line:

```
prepend [] _ _ = []
```

After all, `prepend [] 2 0` should be `[0,0]` and not `[]`. Other than that, it works fine, but you could write it with `concatMap` and `replicate`:

```
concatMap (replicate 2) [1..10]
```

Comment: Or, in infix form, `[1..10] >>= replicate 2`.